# How many residues can a reliable ab initio structural model contain?

Tags: bioinformatics, structural-biology, computational-model

[A recent question on *ab initio*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43315/why-is-ab-initio-protein-secondary-structure-prediction-less-reliable-than-alter) that I answered involved touching on the limitations of *ab initio* modelling. A review from 2009 put forward that typically only in the order of 100-110 residues could be reliably modelled.

7 years after that paper: I just attended a pre-publication presentation in which a 400+ residue structure had been modelled using [I-TASSER](http://zhanglab.ccmb.med.umich.edu/I-TASSER/). The speaker claimed it was reliable and it did fit well in the biological context, but it still needed experimental validation. Unfortunately they had no *in silico* validation scores to hand so I had no handle on how seriously I should take the model.

Ultimately, my question is how many residues can I-TASSER (other modern *ab initio* brands available!) reliably handle for a typical globular domain with today's technology?

Answer (score 2):

Year on year reliable *ab initio* predictions are becoming more common for longer proteins. 400 residues is not an unfeasible length. Of course, loops still remain more of a challenge than helical and sheet secondary structures.

At CASP13, the [Google DeepMind team used AlphaFold](https://deepmind.com/blog/alphafold/) to produce a good quality model ([T0594](http://predictioncenter.org/casp13/results.cgi?view=tables&target=T0954-D1&model=1&groups_id=142)) of a 774 residue protein which is a WD40-repeat of RFWD3 ([6CVZ](https://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/remediatedSequence.do?structureId=6CVZ)). 
All of their CASP13 entries are [here](http://predictioncenter.org/casp13/results.cgi?groups_id=142&submit=Submit).

[image]